# Qual a diferença de NodeList para HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, dom

Estava lendo um código quando me deparei com a seguinte dúvida, gostaria saber se alguém poderia me esclarecer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambas as interfaces são coleções de nós [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM). Eles diferem nos métodos que eles fornecem e no tipo de nós que podem conter. Enquanto um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) pode conter **qualquer tipo de nó**, um [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) deve conter apenas **nós de elementos**(*HTM/XML*).

Um [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) fornece os mesmos métodos que um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) e, adicionalmente, um método chamado `NamedItem()`, que recupera um nó usando um nome. Em documentos *HTML*, ele primeiro procura por um nó com um atributo *id* correspondente, se ele não encontrar um, em seguida, procura por um nó com um atributo *name* correspondente, mas apenas sobre aqueles elementos que são permitidos um atributo *name*.

Em documentos *XHTML*, este método só procura por nós com um atributo *id* correspondente. Vale lembrar que esse método é *case insensitive*, em documentos *HTML* e *case sensitive* em documentos *XHTML*.

Referências:

- [Difference between HTMLCollection and NodeLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)
- [Difference Between Array, NodeList, HTMLCollection](http://xahlee.info/js/js_array_vs_nodelist_vs_html_collection.html)

Comment: Uma outra diferença notável é que HTMLCollection é sempre *live*, enquanto as NodeLists podem ser *live* ou não (segundo a MDN, pelo menos).